# Importing error python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to run this simple test just to get the feel of how to import methods from another script, but I have two problems:

1. the whole program runs instead of just importing and calling, the methods, when I need them too.
2. I'm getting this error:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\devilboy 4\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\classvariablesOnANewScript\classvariablesOnANewScript\classvariablesOnANewScript.py", line 1, in <module>
   from logInScreen import getUser, getPass
   ```

   ImportError: cannot import name getUser

This is the script I'm importing to:

```
from logInScreen import getUser, getPass
class hello:

    def show(self):
        usr = getUser()
        ps = getPass()
        str(usr)
        str(ps)

h = hello()
h.show()
```

This is what's on logInScreen.py :

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import tkinter.messagebox

#check si lo entrado es correcto
class checkValidation:
    fail = 0
    user = "hi user"
    password = "nice pass"

   #valida el user y el pass
    def fullVali(self, name, passwd):
         if  name == "" or name == " ":
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo( "Error","Dejo el usuario en blanco")
            self.fail+= 1
        elif name != "UmetSeg":        
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo( "Error","Usuario incorrecto")
            self.fail+= 1           
        else :
            self.user = name           
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo( "ok","dude" + name)

        if  passwd == "" or passwd == " ":
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo( "Error","Dejo la password en blanco")
            self.fail+= 1
        elif passwd != "SegUmet":            
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo( "Error","Password incorrecto")
            self.fail+= 1            
        else:
            self.password = passwd           
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo( "ok","dude" + passwd)
            form.destroy()

         #open another py script    
            #os.system("mainPage3.py 1")
            return

 # no deja pasar parametros por command en el boton a menos que se por lambda, so corre       #este metodo para 
 #correr el metodo de validar
    def callVali(self):
        user = usrIn.get()
        self.fullVali(usrIn.get(), passIn.get())
        return

    def getUser(self):
        return self.user

    def getPass(self):
        return self.password



vali = checkValidation()
form = Tk()
form.title("LogIn")
form.geometry("300x320+300+200")

#User txtBox
usrIn = Entry(form, textvariable = None, width = 30)
usrIn.place(x = 60, y = 140)
user = usrIn.get()
#Passwd txtBox
passIn = Entry(form, textvariable = None, width = 30)
passIn.place(x = 60, y = 200)
#Username Label
usrLblVal = StringVar()
usrLblVal.set("User name")
usrLbl = Label(form, textvariable = usrLblVal  )
usrLbl.place(x = 120, y = 115)

#Passwrd label
passLblVal = StringVar()
passLblVal.set("Password")
passLbl = Label(form, textvariable = passLblVal  )
passLbl.place(x = 120, y = 175)


#Login btn
btn = Button(form, text = "Entrar", width = 10, command = vali.callVali)
btn.place(x = 110, y = 250)

form.mainloop()
```

I hope I got the indentation right, kinda off a pain going through every line and spacing 4 times till it's right. I apologize for the Spanish, just ignore all the comments lol

Comment: Are you aware you can just highlight all of the code, then click on the button that looks like `{}`? It will automatically add the four spaces for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to import methods from within a `class` in your `LogInScreen.py` file.  The methods `getUser` and `getPass` are `bound methods` that belong to the class `checkValidation`,  You need to instead import the `class` and make the call on your class instead

```
from LogInScreen import checkValidation

validation = checkValidation()
validation.getUser()
validation.getPass()
```

As a simple illustration consider the following example involving two files:

`file_to_import_from.py` (Analogous to your `logInScreen.py`)

```
class MyClass:
    def my_class_bound_method(self):
        print "hello I a method belonging to MyClass"

def my_method_not_belonging_to_a_class():
    print "Hello, I am a method that does not belong to a class"
```

`file_to_import_to.py` (Analogous to the script you are importing to)

```
from file_to_import_from import my_method_not_belonging_to_a_class

my_method_not_belonging_to_a_class()


from file_to_import_from import MyClass

x = MyClass()
x.my_class_bound_method()

from file_to_import_from import my_class_bound_method

my_class_bound_method()
```

And see Output

```
Hello, I am a method that does not belong to a class
hello I a method belonging to MyClass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\Python\import_test2.py", line 10, in <module>
    from file_to_import_from import my_class_bound_method
ImportError: cannot import name my_class_bound_method
```

As you can see, the first two calls worked, but the second time the error you are facing arose, this is because the method `my_class_bound_method` exists as a method within the class `MyClass`.

**EDIT**:

In response to your comment, to avoid running the whole file, surround the code in your 'LogInScreen.py' in an `if` statement which checks if the file being evaluated by the interpreter is the `main` file being run.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import tkinter.messagebox

#check si lo entrado es correcto
class checkValidation:
    # CODE FROM YOUR CLASS OMITTED FOR BREVITY SAKE

# NOTHING BEYOUND THIS IF STATEMENT WILL RUN WHEN THE FILE IS IMPORTED
if __name__ == "__main__":
    vali = checkValidation()
    # MORE CODE OMITTED FOR BREVITY
    form.mainloop()
```

The `if` statement I added here checks a special environment variable that `python` creates when it interprets a file, which is `__name__`, when the file is the file that you are directly running: `python file_i_am_running.py` the variable `__name__` is set the the string `"__main__"` to indicate it is the main method, when it is not the file being run, and maybe one being imported as in your case, the variable is set to the `module` name, i.e. `file_to_import`.

Comment: that fixed one, but when I import the class the whole program runs. Like the window open and everything is placed. I don't want to run the program. Should I place all of the buttons, entry and labels on a method and maybe that fixes it?

Comment: @chelo666  That is due to the nature in which `python` performs an import.  Essentially when you import the whole file, you are asking python to run the file.  This solution can be fixed by the note on my edit.

Comment: Nice, I get it. Thanks.

Comment: is it `__name__` with tow underscore or one `_name_`? Can't really tell

Comment: @chelo666 `__name__` with two underscores `_ _ n a m e _ _` without all that whitespace ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
from logInScreen import checkValidation
```

And then, use:

```
check = checkValidation()
usr = check.getUser()
ps = check.getPass()
```

Comment: your example is wrong. You create an instance called `check`, then call `val.getUser()`. You should be calling `check.getuser()`.

Comment: Thanks, I answered fast.

Comment: I prefer using the same variable instead of using more then one. Thanks for the advice